# How to resolve authentication error when using iSCSI target configuration on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, authentication, centos-7, iscsi

I am attempting to setup an iSCSI target, with one block LUN which is a zfs zvol on a  CentOS 7 machine. I've only ever used iscsitarget and the `/etc/iet/ietd.conf` file on ubuntu systems.

I have this (from `targetcli`):

```
/iscsi> ls
o- iscsi .............................................................................................................. [Targets: 1]
  o- iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main ............................................................................................ [TPGs: 1]
    o- tpg1 ................................................................................................. [no-gen-acls, no-auth]
      o- acls ............................................................................................................ [ACLs: 1]
      | o- iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main:client ........................................................................ [Mapped LUNs: 1]
      |   o- mapped_lun0 .................................................................................. [lun0 block/block1 (rw)]
      o- luns ............................................................................................................ [LUNs: 1]
      | o- lun0 ....................................................................... [block/block1 (/dev/zd0) (default_tg_pt_gp)]
      o- portals ...................................................................................................... [Portals: 1]
        o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ....................................................................................................... [OK]
/iscsi>
```

And I ran this:

```
/iscsi/iqn.20...nas:main/tpg1> set attribute authentication=0
Parameter authentication is now '0'.
/iscsi/iqn.20...nas:main/tpg1>
```

However, a Windows client refuses to connect, and from an Ubuntu machine I receive this authorization error:

```
iscsiadm -m node --targetname "iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main" --portal "192.168.0.146" --login
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main, portal: 192.168.0.146,3260] (multiple)
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main, portal: 192.168.0.146,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (24 - iSCSI login failed due to authorization failure)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

I was not looking to use any CHAP authentication, but I guess if I have to I can. targetcli is entirely new to me, not sure what is missing and from looking around that set attribute command from within tpg1 should have done the trick.

From https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-targetcli/

> No Authentication Authentication is disabled by clearing the TPG
> "authentication" attribute: set attribute authentication=0. Although
> initiator names are trivially forgeable, generate_node_acls still
> works here to either ignore user-defined ACLs and allow all, or check
> that an ACL exists for the connecting initiator

Perhaps I named this incorrectly? As under "acls" I have `iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main:client` but a discovery from clients only returns `iqn.2019-09.com.nas:main`

This is the guide I used to setup:

https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-iscsi-target-initiator-persistently/

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by deleting and recreating, and using my initiator when creating ACL per:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch24.html

Comment: Please do not post a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/243319). Please copy and even quote anything pertinent from that link into the body of your answer here. Links can go away after time but text stored in your answer here will definitely last longer.